# Not getting desired output from Jframe

Tags: java, jframe

I'm new to programming GUI in Java. My code is simple and only needs to do some basic arithmetic but for some reason it's not working. I don't know that I'm using the `String.valueOf()`correctly.

My code:

```
    String restaurantName;
    double subTotal = 0;
    int tipPercentage = 0;
    double totalBill = 0; 
    double tipInDollars = 0;

    restaurantName = txtRestaurantName.getText();
    subTotal = Double.parseDouble(txtSubtotal.getText());
    tipPercentage = Integer.parseInt(txtTipAmt.getText());  
    tipInDollars = ((tipPercentage / 100) * subTotal);
    totalBill = (tipInDollars + subTotal);

    lblDisplayTip.setText(String.valueOf(tipPercentage) + "%");
    lblDisplayTotalBill.setText(String.valueOf(totalBill));
```

If the user enters 50 for subtotal and 10 for the tip percentage, I would expect `tipInDollars` to equal 5 and for `totalBill` to equal 55. 
Yet the output is:
[image]

Comment: The output shows the result of your calculations. There is a bug in your code. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug it and find where the problem occurs. Also read about so-called "integer division" to learn more about how `/` works with `int`s in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not with your display, it's with your calculation, or rather, the variables you use for your calculation. You can either make `tipPercentage` a `double`, or you can make the 100 in this line: `tipInDollars = ((tipPercentage / 100) * subTotal);` into 100.0. Either solution should fix your problem.

The problem arises from dividing an integer (`tipPercentage`) by another integer (100). When you do this, Java will round down and always make your result 0.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate that!